# xbindkeys: pressed key value in command?

Tags: linux

I am trying to configure a hotkey with xbindkeys.
Is it possible to reference the pressed KeyValue in the hotkey-command?
Like:

```
# send hotkeyvalue to pipe
"echo $pressedkey >> /tmp/somepipe"
    m:0x0 + c:75
    F9
```

Q: What is interpreting the command?

Q: And what variables are available?

Comment: Now I implemented the thing myself in c++. Still It would be niche to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect current key press.

It is simple execute your command via execlp

You can view code in github: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/xbindkeys/blob/839da209f2ef8f43e8dc60f28aa7622f386bd0d6/keys.c#L428